# Как "включить" php в Laravel, установленный на WSL 2?

Tags: php, laravel

Поставил laravel на свой linux для Windows. В самой WSL2 у меня установлены и php-cli, и php 7.4, и PHP7.4-fpm и все, что нужно. Во всяком случае, php-скрипты, запускаемые через локальный сервер самой WSL (nginx), прекрасно работают. Но на laravel, если перейти на http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php - php код не отрабатывает, если запустить http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.html c каким-нибудь текстом, то все работает прекрасно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стартовая страница Laravel открывается благополучно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вопрос в чём? Настраивайте nginx, laravel тут не при чем. Стартовая страница - это и есть index.php, роутинг в ларе не учитывает открытие php-файлов, кроме индекса...

Comment: разобрался. Спасибо! и извините, что побеспокоил..